# How to fix scrollable tabs always below the action bar in android

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

In tab it looks like below.

[image]

But in device it looks fine

..[image]

I am looking like below what the google play contained in phones and tabs as same

[image]

this is my oncreate method. I had done scroll tabs with view pager .In  devices it fits good but in tabs ?.I know this is action bar design pattern .

```
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.my_directory_activity);
         final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
         actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
         actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
         actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

         myDirectoryPagerAdapter = new MyDirectoryAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

          mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
          mViewPager.setAdapter(myDirectoryPagerAdapter);

          mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new 
                            ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                     actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

          for (int i = 0; i < myDirectoryPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(myDirectoryPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
            }

           actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

           }
```

Comment: Can you please put a screenshot to show your expected layout and the final outcome in the tablet?

Comment: I just edited my question .Please check once

Answer (score 0):

It will look below the actionbar in the device because the device does not have much space to show all the tabs so the actionbar will manage on its own to show the tabs and adjust it according to the device size. As you have also displayed a logo in actionbar so it will always switch to below.

Answer (score 0):

That is by default for Tabs from Action bar. It is good thing bcoz it saves some screen space for you.

If you dont want it to be present in the action bar. You need to implement it separately. Use PagerTitleStrip.

Two implementations here:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip